# Python Newspaper subheading

Tags: python, python-newspaper

I want to extract the SUBHEADING of this and other articles:
https://www.dr.dk/nyheder/regionale/trekanten/legos-regnskab-viser-tilbagegang

That is: "Lego har netop præsenteret regnskabet for 2017, og kurven peger nedad."

However, it doesn't seem like the python module Newspaper can do just that.

Am I missing something?
Are there other modules that can? I've also tried readability and html2text.

My code:

```
from newspaper import Article

url = 'https://www.dr.dk/nyheder/regionale/trekanten/legos-regnskab-viser-tilbagegang'
article = Article(url)

article.download()
article.parse()

print (article.title)
print (article.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use:

```
print(article.meta_description)
```

which will print the subheading of the article.

Comment: This graps the subheading from a meta-tag in <head>, not in the article text. The problem is other newspapers don't display their subheadings here. Fx. https://politiken.dk/indland/art6367735/For%C3%A6ldre-skal-spores-for-b%C3%B8rnenes-skyld